# Excel Addin StartUp Event . Get Opening Workbook Path

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, excel-addins

I need to intercept the StartUp event of an Excel Addin using **Interop**, and modify the opening of an excel based on the commandLine arguments.
The only thing i'm missing is the path of the file that excel is opening. I can't find this path between the commandLine argument, nor i can use the **ActiveWorkbook.Path** property, since i already tried and no workbook is active during the execution of the StartUp method (hence i only get an exception).
How can i get this information?

(to be clear, i was expecting to find a  GetCommandLineArgs content similar to:

```
[0] "C:\Program Files\etcet\EXCEL.EXE"
[1] "C:\Users\Myself\Documents\ExcelDocINeeToOpen.xlsx"
[2] "-Embedding"
```

but i only see the path of the App and the the other parm, not the path of the file being opened.

Thanks